# SESSION TIMEOUT PRIMEFACES?

Tags: jquery, jsf, session, primefaces, timeout

i want to implement a countdown clock, and then finish my actual session when the time finish and redirect me to the login page, how can i do that i PRIMEFACES ... I dont want to use IdleMonitor because i want to display a message for login again when my countdown finish and is very important for me to show the remaining time
i have this

```
     $(function() {
          $('#time').chrony({
          second: 15,
          finish: function() {
          this.html('Finished!'); -- Here i want to call a logout function and redirect to login page
      }
    });
 });
```

this is a jquery timedown clock, but i want to call me a beanSessionTimeout when it finish

I read about remoteCommand in primefaces... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use `p:remoteCommand` like this:

```
<-- this goes somehwere on your page -->
<p:remoteCommand name="timeout" action="#{bean.sessionTimeout}" />
```

and your javascript:

```
 $(function() {
      $('#time').chrony({
      second: 15,
      finish: function() {
      this.html('Finished!'); 
      timeout();
    }
  });
});
```

But maybe it's worth considering using a [framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html) to help you with user authentication and session lifetime management.

Comment: i put your code but when i start the page, automaticaly call the remoteCommand and my clock doesnt show

Comment: Hmm.. this shouldn't happen - which version of Primefaces are you using? Are you sure that there isn't another call to `timeout()` somewhere on the page?